# How should one change the width of scrollbar?

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, gtk

I started using Linux Mint 13 Mate a few days ago and I can't find anyway to change the width of my scrollbar, no matter it is firefox, chrome or File Manager.

I tried to search google with "Linux Mint 13 scrollbar size" or "Linux scrollbar size" as keywords but the result isn't useful.

I looked up all the option in Control Center and found nothing so I doubt they have a option in Linux Mint 13. Actually it is quite a failure although they claim Linux Mint is user friendly.

If anyone knows which linux distro has this option please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Scroll bars are provided by the gtk/qt theme for the window manager. You can use a tool like `lxappearance` to change gtk themes...

Answer (score 5):

The width of the scrollbars depends on the Widget toolkit in use by your Desktop Environment not on the distro itself. This means that width is specified by the theme(GTK, QT, etc).

Because you are using Mint, I'm pretty certain it's GTK in your case, so changing the theme would be enough to influence it. Many sites have a great selection of them(just google "gtk themes" :D).

Also, you can manually override it by creating a file called `.gtkrc-2.0` in your home folder with the following line `slider-width=X` where `X` is the desired width in pixels.

**EDIT:** Here's a list of all the gtk properties of scrolllbars, it might come in hand. https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes/GtkScrollbar

**EDIT2:** Sorry, I didn't realize I forgot to mention that the that the option in `gtkrc-2.0` has to be associated with a widget. The correct way would be:

```
style "scrollbar-style"
{
   slider-width = 9 # for example
}

class "GtkScrollbar"   style "scrollbar-style"
class "GtkVScrollbar"  style "scrollbar-style"
class "GtkHScrollbar"  style "scrollbar-style"
```

Similarly you can open your gtk theme file and search the same property and adjust it. Either way it requires a refresh for the latter and a logout for the former.

Comment: Does your answer appy to Linux Mint 13 Mate only? Does it apply to its XFCE version?

Comment: Any DE that uses GTK, so yeah, XFCE included.

Comment: The manual option doesn't work.....and I don't know which theme you are talking about. Obviously the theme only available for Control/Color/Window Border/Icon/Pointer, in which no one is related to the scroll bar.

Comment: I added a little edit in response, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

2019 Update:

Google brought me here for something similar - how to get a wider vertical scrollbar as the current scrollbar was just way too narrow...

```
 # cd ~/.config/gtk-3.0/
 # touch gtk.css
```

Then add in ;

```
 .scrollbar.vertical slider,
  scrollbar.vertical slider {
     min-width: 15px;
 }
```

And voila - you have wider vertical scrollbars !!!

Note my specific environment was a XFCE Desktop in a OpenSuse box. YMMV.

Comment: It worked with my environment: Linux Mint 19 - Cinnamon

Answer (score 1):

2020 Update

In Mint Linux 19.3, scrollbars can be adjusted using Themes settings. Select The system menu, then select Themes from the Preferences menu to open the Themes settings dialog. Select the Settings tab. From there, turn on "Override the current theme's scrollbar width". Then, you can adjust the width with the slider.

[image]